# How to call ioctl from kernel space in Linux kernel 5.10?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, chaining, ioctl

My driver's IOCTL handler redirects IOCTL requests to another driver. This used to work great, but when I needed to add support for the 5.10 kernel, it turned out that the old way didn't work anymore. How can this be done now?

```
#define TARGET_ID "TGT"
// ...
char id[sizeof(TARGET_ID)];
// ...
mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
res = __blkdev_driver_ioctl(dev->bdev_raw, 0, SCSI_IOCTL_TARGET_ID, (unsigned long)id);
set_fs(old_fs);

if(0 == strcmp(id, TARGET_ID))
{
    PINFO("*** target driver detected! ***\n");
    dev->is_target_driver = true;
}
else
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooray! Hooray! Hooray! ;) This is how it will work:

```
    #define TARGET_ID "TGT"
    // ...
    char id[sizeof(TARGET_ID)];
    // ...
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 15, 4)
    mm_segment_t old_fs = force_uaccess_begin();
    res = __blkdev_driver_ioctl(dev->bdev_raw, 0, SCSI_IOCTL_TARGET_ID, (unsigned long)id);
    force_uaccess_end(old_fs);
#else
    mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    res = __blkdev_driver_ioctl(dev->bdev_raw, 0, SCSI_IOCTL_TARGET_ID, (unsigned long)id);
    set_fs(old_fs);
#endif
    
    if(0 == strcmp(id, TARGET_ID))
    {
        PINFO("*** target driver detected! ***\n");
        dev->is_target_driver = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that `force_uaccess_begin()` cannot replace `set_fs(KERNEL_DS);`
Below is its definition:

```
static inline mm_segment_t force_uaccess_begin(void)
{
    mm_segment_t fs = get_fs();

    set_fs(USER_DS);
    return fs;
}
```

And `mm_segment_t`, `force_uaccess_begin` all have been removed after linux 5.18.